# Remote Linux machine to Windows VPN Server

Tags: linux, windows-server-2003, vpn, samba

I have our Win2K3 server setup as a VPN pptp server.  It works 100% no problem from remote clients.

I've setup a remote linux server running samba.  Its sole purpose is to be an offsite backup for our backup server.  Basically an offsite NAS BOX.

I want to connect the remote linux server over VPN.  So should the remote linux be running a VPN client or VPN server?

Thank you,
Shai

Comment: I don't get it. Do whatever is easier?

Comment: I have a tendency to run PoPToP on Linux and let the Windows machines be clients; but this was because I could never get pptpclient to work. I have to admit ubuntu (and possible others) have solved that problem nicely!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just VPN into the Windows Server machine using a VPN client on the Linux server. Just makes things easier and has the same effect. pptpclient.sourceforge.net FTW!! =)

Comment: Thank you for the great info. Simple solutions are the best. Thanks again!

Comment: You're quite welcome. =)